# Solve equation: Is $x=y$ the only solution?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $0<x\leqslant y<\infty$ and $r,s$ be given positive integers. I would like to solve

$$\frac{sx^{s-1}-ry^{s-1}}{sy^{r-1}-rx^{r-1}} = \frac{sy^{s-1}-rx^{s-1}}{sx^{r-1}-ry^{r-1}}$$

for $x$ and for $y$.

I only get that, obviously, $x=y$ is a solution (not depending on the values of $r$ and $s$).

---

After some calculations, I get
$$
-\frac{syx^s-rxy^s}{ryx^r-sxy^r}=\frac{ryx^s-sxy^s}{rxy^r-syx^r}
$$

Comment: Well, what do you get after cross-multiplying, expanding, and simplifying?

Comment: added it, sorry. i forgot to write it down

Comment: Cross-multiplying means $$ (sx^{s-1}-ry^{s-1}) (sx^{r-1}-ry^{r-1}) = (sy^{s-1}-rx^{s-1}) (sy^{r-1}-rx^{r-1}) \, .$$ Then expand the products, cancel equal terms on both sides, simplify ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just divide by ($y^{s-1}$) $\&$ ($y^{r-1}$) in the numerator & denominator respectively in LHS & RHS,

Then, let $t = \frac{y}{x}.$

& cross multiply the denominators to both sides.

Simplify the equation to get :

$(s^2 - r^2)((t)^{s+r-2} - 1) = 0.$

Hence,

Case 1 : $|s| = |r|$ gives all positive integer pairs $(x,y)$ with $x,y$ distinct as solutions.

Case 2 : all $(x,y)$ with $x=y$ are solutions only when $|s|,|r|$ are unequal.